# How to improve the image quality when images are in drawable folder

Tags: android, image, imageview

Before I tried this ,  Store image in R.drawable folder ..

```
 Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image1);
```

and then in database using insert sql statement.  Image was much better.

Now I have stored data in string array,   all images in R.drawable folder and displaying them in image view using 
            imageview.setImageResource(image[i]);
But image is very small and  not visible properly. what can I do improve the image quality?

thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final image size depends also, in which folder you store images: drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-ldpi. When you put images into hdpi folder, their appearance is smaller than from mdpi and ldpi. Try to read this documentation: [Screen Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Another enhancement can be achieved by declaring 24bit color support, so images with alpha channel will have smooth gradients: `activity.getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);` but it requires more performance to process.

Comment: Thank you for replying.What about storing images in raw folder? What is the difference in storing in R.drawable and R.raw ? After posting this question, tried to put all images in raw folder,and  it displayed still not clear but better images than storing in R.drawable.

Comment: The main difference is, that files in drawable folder are automatically processed and optimized to use. They may be scaled and automatically converted into RGB565 colorspace to get higher performance. If your image has an alpha channel you should store it in raw folder or enable the RGBA_8888 format like I wrote, so it will be "saved" from these optimizations.