# Why android lose image quality when displaying a png file?

Tags: android, image

I want to display a png image on android. This is the image file:

[image]

The right end is a bit darker than left.

But the quality of image lost on android application(using ImageView):

[image]

Please note part in the red frame. The color is not changing smoothly.

But if I use the browser of my android phone, it plays good(so it's not reason of the phone screen):

[image]

This is my android code, which is pretty simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="@drawable/hhh"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

where `hhh` is my first image posted here, which is under `res/drawable`.

I test it on my android phone(android 2.3.6) and android simulator(with android 2.2/2.3/4.0), all do not display good. But it plays good on my android pad(android 4.0.3).

What's the problem, and how to fix it?

Comment: Try saving png with alpha channel,(pixels not perfectly opaque) from your image editor.

Comment: Have you tried using code to set the ImageView?

Using code you can enable more options

There's a similar questions whose answer may help u.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312996/how-to-improve-the-image-quality-when-images-are-in-drawable-folder

Comment: http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/12/08/bitmap-quality-banding-and-dithering/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Images in `res/drawable` are compressed. [This is supposed to be lossless](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html), but I've heard of similar issues in the past.

Move it into `res/raw`, and give it a go.

Comment: I just tried `res/raw`, but no lucky. I moved the image to `res/raw`, and changed the code to `<ImageView ... android:background="@raw/hhh" />`, it didn't display well.

Comment: The issue you have is banding, have you tried dithering? This has some options/workarounds

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769885/androiddither-true-does-not-dither-whats-wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your `Activity` and see if it helps.

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
   super.onAttachedToWindow();
   Window window = getWindow();
   //eliminates color banding
   window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This problem is a well-know it is a gradient banding issues, I have this problen and solve by add noise, such as http://planetphotoshop.com/say-goodbye-to-gradient-banding.html